# systemd-python AttributeError: module 'systemd.journal' has no attribute 'JournaldLogHandler'

Tags: python, pip

I installed `systemd-python`:

`pip install systemd-python`

My python code:

```
from systemd import journal
...
log = logging.getLogger('lookup')
log.addHandler(journal.JournaldLogHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/lookup.py", line 12, in <module>
    log.addHandler(journal.JournaldLogHandler())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'systemd.journal' has no attribute 'JournaldLogHandler'. Did you mean: 'JournalHandler'?
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong package. Instead of `systemd-python`, you need `cysystemd` (which is the same as the `systemd` package - but we should avoid this confusing alias)

#### Install cysystemd:

###### 1. Install the required linux packages:

- For Debian/Ubuntu users:

`apt install build-essential libsystemd-dev`

- On older versions of Debian/Ubuntu, you might also need to install:

`apt install libsystemd-daemon-dev libsystemd-journal-dev`

- For CentOS/RHEL

`yum install gcc systemd-devel`

###### 2. Install package with pip

`pip install cysystemd`

###### 3. Don't forget to change your import

`from cysystemd import journal`